# Delete javascript backtick string

Tags: cut-copy-paste

In Javascript you can write multiline strings like this:

```js
s=`hello
world`
```

I would like to delete/yank the inside of the string by pressing di` etc., however that doesn't work. What do I have to add to my vimrc etc. to make it work?

Comment: Text objects like `i"` only work on a single line. I don't program much JavaScript, but there might be a plugin which adds smarter text objects for stuff like this (which will probably also deal with escapes and whatnot). Other than that, implementing your own motion to override the default is probably the easiest. Don't have time to write a full implementation, but there's a few resources on how to do that ([1](https://old.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/48e4ci/vimscript_how_to_create_a_new_text_object/), [2](https://jdhao.github.io/2020/11/15/nvim_text_objects/)) which may be helpful.